# JQuery using string as variable name

Tags: jquery, variables, real-time, names

This code is used to update a chart when it recieves data

```
GraphChannel.on("data", function (newdata) {
    var newdataobj = JSON.parse(newdata), updateGraph = "#graph"+newdataobj.ID, updateData = "data"+newdataobj.ID, updateOptions = "options"+newdataobj.ID;
    incrementArray(newdataobj.ID, newdataobj.Data);
    $.plot(updateGraph, [ updateData ], updateOptions);
    console.log(newdataobj);
    console.log(updateGraph);
    console.log(updateData);
    console.log(updateOptions);
});
```

The console logs are:

```
Object {ID=0, Data=1}
#graph0
data0
options0
```

If I remove the variables and use 0 as the ID and 1 as the Data, the code should look like this:

```
GraphChannel.on("data", function (newdata) {
    incrementArray(0, 1);
    $.plot("#graph0", [ data0 ], options0);
});
```

I'm not sure why this won't work though

Increment Array:

```
function incrementArray(array, letter){
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var subArray = array[i];
    if(subArray[0] == letter){
        subArray[1]++;
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does the `incrementArray` function do?

Comment: @StijnMartens It increment a value in an array by 1, I know that this is not the reason for the issue but I have added the function to my code

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The variables `data0` and `options0` are not set?

Comment: @StijnMartens I wish to update my flot graph when the channel receives data, but there can be a different number of graphs on the page so they all have ID's like graph0 and graph2. The variables have been set, I just cut the code.

Comment: Your question is still vague.

Comment: @StijnMartens I guess the best way to explain it is that I want to treat a string as a variable name

Comment: Just don't. Use arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to use `eval()`.
But that is not a good practice.

What is a good practice is using arrays:

```
// Store all your data in an array
var data = [
    'data for plot 0',
    'data for plot 1'
]

// Store all your options in an array
var options [
    {
        //options for plot 0
    },
    {
        //options for plot 1
    }
]
```

Then when you want the data for plot 0, you can use:

```
data[0];

// In your case
var updateData = data[newdataobj.ID];
```

So your code becomes something like:

```
GraphChannel.on("data", function (newdata) {
    var newdataobj = JSON.parse(newdata)
    var updateGraph = "#graph"+newdataobj.ID;
    var updateData = data[newdataobj.ID];
    var updateOptions = options[newdataobj.ID];

    //incrementArray(newdataobj.ID, newdataobj.Data); This function does nothing?

    $.plot(updateGraph, [ updateData ], updateOptions);
});
```

But I think there's still something not right. You say you want to update the plot when you receive data. But shouldn't you use that new data to put in the graph then?
Instead of using existing data stored in the document already.

If I take that in consideration, I think your overall code should be like:

```
var options [
    {
        //options for plot 0
    },
    {
        //options for plot 1
    }
]

GraphChannel.on("data", function (newdata) {
    var newdataobj = JSON.parse(newdata)
    var updateGraph = "#graph"+newdataobj.ID;
    var updateOptions = options[newdataobj.ID];

    // Use the newdataobj.Data:
    $.plot(updateGraph, [ newdataobj.Data ], updateOptions);
});
```